# Global variables VS localStorage in web app and memory issues

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'm wondering which would be better practice. Polluting the global namespace with global variables for intra-session persistence or using localStorage instead?

So in other words set a global variable on launch, change its value in a function when required and reference it in a third function, or use `localStorage.setItem` then `localStorage.removeItem` when the value is no longer needed?

Will doing either one increase memory efficiency?

Comment: Check this test http://jsperf.com/localstorage-vs-globals

Answer (score 7):

LocalStorage is primarily for persistent data across sessions. 
In your case, as your looking for an *intra-session* persistence, global variables have clear advantages.

I will start with cons of global variables first.

- It uses the global namespace, any third party js code can manipulate it
- A page refresh can wipe off your data

Well, that's it. If we consider the cons of LocalStorage, the list will raise your eyebrows.

- set and get are slow and can be a performance bottleneck for large datasets
- only strings are allowed; you may have to serialize your data before setting

I would surely vote up for LocalStorage if your use case involved *inter-session* storage. However, in your scenario, the only benefit you see is the removeItem function for which you have the delete counterpart for global variables.

This article may be helpful: http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-browser-storage-past-present-future/

Answer (score -3):

As now consider to using DI in frameworks like Angular.